# Flexslider Plugin Slides Are out of Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

My problem is about Flexslider plugin. I don't know why slides are out of order. Considering my markup:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>First Slide</li>
    <li>Second Slide</li>
    <li>Third Slide</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have this result:

First li appears as second slide, second li as third slide, and third li as first slide.

This problem appears when I add animation: "slide" option, like this:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide"});
});
```

I'm confused, maybe somewhere in my code some CSS causes this behavior.

Comment: I've had the same problem, fixed according to your remark; removed `animation: "slide"`

Comment: @icezAz read my answer to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is a bug in flexslider version 2.2.2 download package. Even the demo file in the downloaded package does not work fine, really!

After so much investigation I found out the "jquery.flexslider.js" has problem and got a working file from version 2.2.0.

The solution: Get a working package version 2.2.0. If you are interested make a comment to make a working package available to you for download.

Comment: I was having the same issue and it seems it was indeed the corrupted .js file in the package. I just downloaded a fresh copy from github and it has been fixed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a corruption, just a bug in 2.2.2
The github issues list references a patch for it, but it still hasn't been deployed in a stable release

Comment: You saved my sanity tonight!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is going wrong without all of the code, but this may be a solution for you.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide", startAt: 0});
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This is because you put the slides in an unordered list, when you should use ordered list like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide"});
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>First Slide</li>
        <li>Second Slide</li>
        <li>Third Slide</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Try the updated code. Make sure that you load the flexslider.css before JS and you use $(window).load

Comment: No this is not the case.

Comment: Did you put JS inside the <head> element?
Did you link the CSS, jQuery and FlexSlider to your page?
Please provide the full code for your page.